# How to stop my footer design to effect the whole page?

Tags: html, css

I made this footer but when I include it in my base.html it changes the styling of the other parts I think due to its CSS and it makes some icons look strange what should I do?? if I need to post another part of code please let me know

Thanks in advance

my index.html (footer)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="vieport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <footer>
        <div class="footerContainer" >
            <div class="socialIcons">
                <a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-telegram"></i></a>
                <a href="https://github.com/Jasmine-dy"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="footerNav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Genres</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Your Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="footerBottom">
            <p style="margin-top: 10px" >Copyright &copy;2023; Designed by <span class="designer">Jasmine</span> </p>
            <a href="https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-background-with-rainbow-coloured-hologram-background_19613969.htm#query=pastel%20holographic%20background&position=2&from_view=keyword&track=ais&uuid=eccfffcb-4044-4b17-8749-40b272baa47e">Image by kjpargeter</a> on <span class="designer"> Freepik</span>
            <h2></h2>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icon/79363/reading-unicorn">Reading Unicorn</a> icon by <a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
<style>
    footer{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.footerContainer{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 30px 20px;
}
.socialIcons{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.socialIcons a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
}
.socialIcons a i{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #f48fb1;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

/* Hover Effects on Social Media Icons*/
.socialIcons a:hover{
    background-color: #f48fb1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.socialIcons a:hover i{
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.footerNav{
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.footerNav ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.footerNav ul li a{
    color: #49464e;
    margin: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.footerNav ul li a:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

.footerBottom{
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footerBottomp{
    color: white;
}

.designer{
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px){
    .footerNav ul{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .footerNav ul li{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
</style>
</html>
```

my base.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>  {% block title %}{% endblock %}  </title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'website/favicon.ico' %}" />
</head>
  <body>
    {% include 'top-menu.html'%}
    <div class="container">
      {% if messages %}
       {% for message in messages %}
         <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
           <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% block content %}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
  {% include 'index.html'%}
</html>
```

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qllfn.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your footer (index.html) disturbs the layout, it may be due to CSS conflicts.

To prevent CSS conflicts and ensure that the footer's styling doesn't interfere with other parts of your website, you can encapsulate the footer's CSS within a unique class or ID specific to the footer. Be conscious when you re-use same CSS classes on elements.

```
 <!-- footer.html -->
<footer class="custom-footer">
  <!-- ... existing footer content ... -->
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer though I tried it but it does not work as long as it is included in my base.html the whole page keeps showing up like that